# Restrict data access

Tags: sql-server, wpf, ssas

I have a SQL Server 2014 Database with Analysis services and have created an Initial CUBE using Visual studio 2013. All works as expected however I want to be able to restrict specific users to specific data within the cube.

On all of the dimensions there is a field called "ACCOUNT" and what I need to do is restrict users to specific accounts only. The user should not be able to change or alter this list. I am using both EXCEL and Teleriks RadPivotGrid for WPF as the client front end. I know that telerik has a report filter which I can add to programmatically however the user can remove and/or change this filter which I cannot allow the user to do.

I may have data within about 700 different accounts on it and does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to implement this would be to set up roles on SSAS, and then apply dimension security using the roles.

I.e. Assign 1 or more members in your dimension to a role, and assign your users to that role.

Here's the Books Online pages:

[Dimension Data (Role Designer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188959(v=sql.105).aspX)

[Security Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188959(v=sql.105).aspX)

Here's a basic step through: [Introduction to Dimension Security](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1834/introduction-to-dimension-security-in-sql-server-analysis-services-ssas-2005/)

Comment: Thanks for that but in fact I found the answer using the ADOMDDataProvider and programmatically adding filters before the query is sent. Works pretty well with the only caveat is if they use any other tool than our own to query the cube then that security will not be enforced. Works for us though as our app is the only way customers will be able to access the cube.